# apache2 mpm_event does not react to config changes

Tags: apache2

I want to increase the amount of parallel open connections (read:*server got requests but needs time to process before answering and client is waiting*). I wrote a test php script to test whether I achieved my goal hosted on the apache2 instance:

```
<?php
$time = new DateTime();
echo date_timestamp_get($time);
echo "<br>Hello World";
sleep(20);
echo "<br>bye world<br>";
$time = new DateTime();
echo date_timestamp_get($time);
?>
```

Apache version information:

```
apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 17 2016 11:09:09
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/bitnami/lampstack-linux-x64/output/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/bitnami/lampstack-linux-x64/output/apache2/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

The loaded modules are:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

The configuration related to mpm modules in `httpd.conf` is :

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
[...]
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers    20
  MinSpareServers 20
  MaxSpareServers 20
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    MaxRequestWorkers       20
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  5000
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    MaxClients              20
    MaxRequestsPerChild     5000
  </IfVersion>
  KeepAliveTimeout 1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
  ServerLimit               15
  StartServers              15
  MinSpareThreads         128
  MaxSpareThreads         192
  ThreadsPerChild          64
  MaxRequestWorkers       256
  MaxConnectionsPerChild 5000
  KeepAliveTimeout          2
</IfModule>
```

I am (manually) running 8 requests in my browser accessing the test script and would expect the `access.log` output to show that the requests are all finished within mere seconds of each other. But the output of the log shows a different picture:

```
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:00:43 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:03 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:05 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:05 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:06 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:07 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 58
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:23 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 59
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Aug/2017:21:01:25 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 59
```

The output in my browser matches the `access.log` output:

```
1.
1502917243
Hello World
bye world
1502917263

2.
1502917263
Hello World
bye world
1502917283

3.
1502917265
Hello World
bye world
1502917285

4.
1502917265
Hello World
bye world
1502917286

5.
1502917266
Hello World
bye world
1502917286

6.
1502917267
Hello World
bye world
1502917287

7.
1502917283
Hello World
bye world
1502917303

8.
1502917285
Hello World
bye world
1502917305
```

The first request is processed and when this is done the next five are processed and then the remaining ones are processed and it is easy to see that the delay between batches is due to the processes still being held open by the sleep command.

I **DID** restart the apache service after changing the configuration.
I **DID** restart the whole machine after changing the configuration.
Neither action resulted in different results so my theory is that I did not do the configuration correctly.

Using `top` to list the active processes and filtering using `COMMAND=httpd.bin` shows the following picture:

```
 1298 root      20   0  136508   4624   2876 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.15 httpd.bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 1347 daemon    20   0  876188   7192   2412 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.61 httpd.bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 1348 daemon    20   0  876188   6956   2260 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.61 httpd.bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 1349 daemon    20   0 1072796   7364   2416 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.62 httpd.bin
```

**How do I fix this/Where did my configuration go wrong?**

Comment: there is no `mpm-event` tag and I have not enough rep to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and debugging I finally found the reason. The `php-fpm.bin` worker were limited to 5 at a time. Increasing `pm.max_children` to a higher number in the corresponding config file fixed the problem.